# Subscribe to a redis channel in Django project

Tags: django, redis, microservices, publish-subscribe

I have multiple applications written with nodejs or python/django or ...
These services are working fine. But need to have pub/sub Async communication with each other.

In nodejs there is no problem and easily can pub/sub to any redis channel.

**Question:** My question is how can i continuously subscribe to a redis channel and receive data published with other services?

**Note:** many links suggest to use django-channels. But I guess that's not the way to do it. If so can any one help me and give details on how to do it.

**Update:**
Django by default is not event-based like nodejs. So if i use a redis client, I should for example check redis every second and see if anything is published or not. I don't think using just a redis client in python will be enough.

Really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don’t you use Redis Pub/Sub in python django. I mean, why you can’t use Redis in django?  Subscribe to channel from NodeJS?

Comment: I haven't worked it yet. But using `django-celery`[link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) can be a good option for async pub/subs task.

Comment: The problem is django is not event-based. If i want to have nodejs like performance, I should use real-time frameworks of django. like twisted.

Comment: And django-celery I did used. But it's more of a task-queue. I don't think that's the exact solution for my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of alternatives. If you have [FIFO](https://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/what-is-fifo) issue you have to use queues in order to connect one microservice to another. For me, if you don’t have Big Data problem you can use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com), It is very practical and very effective, otherwise if you have Big Data problem you can use [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org). There are wide variety services.

If you want just Pub/Sub. The best tool is Redis, It is very fast and easy to integrate. If you are concerned how to implement it in Python just look at [article](https://medium.com/@johngrant/python-redis-pub-sub-6e26b483b3f7)

#### [Update]

It's possible to create a `manage.py` command in django and subscribe to redis in that management file and execute this script separated from django server:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
def handle(self, *args, **options):

    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=1)
    p = r.pubsub()
    p.psubscribe('topic.*')
    for message in p.listen():
        if message:
            print('message received, do anything you want with it.')
```

Comment: So you are saying that I should run a python script beside my django application that always listen to redis. But i miss the ORM features of django. What if i create a `manage.py` script in django and look for anything that published on redis?

Comment: It is also an option. I assume you also can use [Django Redis Pub/Sub](https://pypi.org/project/django-redis-pubsub/) library.

Comment: No it's not what I want. I just want a simple pub/sub solution with redis for django.

Comment: And what happens if you want to deploy this in production?

Answer (score 6):

In order to handle subscriptions to redis, you will need to have a separate continuously running process (server) which listens to redis and then makes something with your data. `django-channels` will do the same by running the code in a `worker`

As pointed above, Django provides convenient way to run "servers" by using `Django management command` approach. When running a django management command, you have complete access to your code, i.e. to ORM as well.

Only detail that you mentioned `Async` communication. Here you need to take into account that Django's ORM is strictly sync code, and you need to pay attention how you want to use ORM with async code. Probably you need to clarify what do you mean by `async` here.

As for redis messages processing, you can use any libraries that work with it. For example, `aioredis` or `redis-py`